# Unable to open mht file in WebView when updating Chrome v77

Tags: android, google-chrome, kotlin, android-webview

I can't open mht files in WebView.
It worked fine until Chrome v76, but v77 had a read error

If chrome is returned to v76, the read was successful.
file: /// also didn't work.
Loading with loadDataWithBaseURL also didn't work

```
webview.loadUrl("file://{$context.cacheDir}/file.mht")
```

cid: Frame- "Random string" @ mhtml.blink
Net :: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SHCEME

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late answer because i face same problem and i was searching solution yesterday and i resolve it today like below.

In your java class you have to give below code

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                if (one_time==1)//one_time is only a variable because i want
                                // to run view.loadUrl(url); only one time.
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                one_time++;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {

            }

        });
```

I think you are giving

```
   view.loadUrl(url);
```

in below method

```
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
     // view.loadUrl(url); like this
     // you will need this when you will load the url but in case 
     //of mht page it will not work 
     return true;
  }
```

do not do this if you are loading mht page because

```
 shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){...}
```

loads the url and it also run when first time you open webview activity.

so,

```
onLoadResource(WebView view, String url){...}
```

method load the Resource.